# Move item up one layer in Illustrator programmatically

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am working on a project where I need to move hundreds of objects up one layer in Illustrator. Like this:

- Select Object
- Move up one layer
- Select another object
- Move up one layer
- etc.

I want a keyboard shortcut for "move up one layer."

I found a potential solution using scripting here:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/472211

But it doesn't work - I think that the scripting specifications have changed since that thread was originally written. So the specific help I need it this: How do I update this older script to work with current extendScript in Illustrator:

```
//DESCRIPTION: One Layer Up  
for (s=0; s<app.selection.length; s++)  
{  
if (app.selection[s].itemLayer.index > 0)  
  app.selection[s].itemLayer = 
app.activeDocument.layers.previousItem(app.selection[s].itemLayer);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved this:

```
//DESCRIPTION: One Layer Up  
var docSelected = app.activeDocument.selection;
var topLayer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];
var bottomLayer = app.activeDocument.layers[1];
for (s = 0; s < docSelected.length; s++)   
{  
     myPath = docSelected[s];
     topLayer.visible = true;
     myPath.move(topLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
     topLayer.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: My specific document only has two layers, so I didn't need to solve for moving up one layer.